# less (ver. 2.5.3) vs Rhino(or Nashorn)

Tags: javascript, less, rhino

The situation is - I have this issue on [less GitHub](https://github.com/less/less.js/issues/2316)
the topic is "Rhino doesn't work with less older 2.X.X", but also I have that manual from the [official less site](http://lesscss.org/#command-line-with-rhino), it says that compilation is very simple! All you need is to run command from you command line. But it doesn't work for me.
So my question is very simple - is there anywhere any topic of HOW to compile less 2.5.3 version(or near it) with Rhino(or maybe, Nashorn), maybe there are some trics or things not clear for the first sight. Or a topic with the clear "NO YOU CAN'T DO IT!" from the developers.

Comment: [Have you seen this other bug?](https://github.com/less/less.js/issues/2063)

Comment: https://github.com/less/less-docs/issues/326 - the documentation may not be continuously updated to reflect the current project state. And the topic you're looking for is https://github.com/less/less.js/issues/2316.

Comment: You cannot. The latest Less Rhino compiler is compatible with Less 1.7.5.

Comment: @agabrys can you give me any official remarks for this question from the developers, so I can show it to my teamlead?

Comment: I started looking and found that the latest Less version ([2.5.1](https://github.com/less/less.js/releases/tag/v2.5.1)) contains `less-rhino/index.js` file. So maybe it works... I'm the author of the [biz.gabrys.maven.plugins:lesscss-maven-plugin](https://github.com/gabrysbiz/lesscss-maven-plugin) and I had problem to launch it in November 2015. Maybe I did something wrong. I will check it again...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the answer is **NO YOU CAN'T DO IT** (for now).
There is an unsolved issue in GitHub issue tracking system: [Rhino Support in 2.x](https://github.com/less/less.js/issues/2316).

I also tried to compile less sources using Less 2.5.1 and Rhino. Unfortunately it does not work:

```
org.mozilla.javascript.EcmaError: ReferenceError: "window" is not defined. (file:/D:/Projects/lesscss/sources/compiler/target/classes/less/less.js#72)
at org.mozilla.javascript.ScriptRuntime.constructError(ScriptRuntime.java:3689)
at org.mozilla.javascript.ScriptRuntime.constructError(ScriptRuntime.java:3667)
at org.mozilla.javascript.ScriptRuntime.notFoundError(ScriptRuntime.java:3752)
at org.mozilla.javascript.ScriptRuntime.nameOrFunction(ScriptRuntime.java:1793)
at org.mozilla.javascript.ScriptRuntime.name(ScriptRuntime.java:1732)
at org.mozilla.javascript.gen.file__D__Projects_lesscss_sources_compiler_target_classes_less_less_js_1._c_anonymous_8(file:/D:/Projects/lesscss/sources/compiler/target/classes/less/less.js:72)
at org.mozilla.javascript.gen.file__D__Projects_lesscss_sources_compiler_target_classes_less_less_js_1.call(file:/D:/Projects/lesscss/sources/compiler/target/classes/less/less.js)
at org.mozilla.javascript.ScriptRuntime.applyOrCall(ScriptRuntime.java:2429)
at org.mozilla.javascript.BaseFunction.execIdCall(BaseFunction.java:269)
at org.mozilla.javascript.IdFunctionObject.call(IdFunctionObject.java:97)
at org.mozilla.javascript.optimizer.OptRuntime.callN(OptRuntime.java:52)
at org.mozilla.javascript.gen.file__D__Projects_lesscss_sources_compiler_target_classes_less_less_js_1._c_s_4(file:/D:/Projects/lesscss/sources/compiler/target/classes/less/less.js:13)
at org.mozilla.javascript.gen.file__D__Projects_lesscss_sources_compiler_target_classes_less_less_js_1.call(file:/D:/Projects/lesscss/sources/compiler/target/classes/less/less.js)
at org.mozilla.javascript.optimizer.OptRuntime.callName(OptRuntime.java:63)
at org.mozilla.javascript.gen.file__D__Projects_lesscss_sources_compiler_target_classes_less_less_js_1._c_e_3(file:/D:/Projects/lesscss/sources/compiler/target/classes/less/less.js:13)
at org.mozilla.javascript.gen.file__D__Projects_lesscss_sources_compiler_target_classes_less_less_js_1.call(file:/D:/Projects/lesscss/sources/compiler/target/classes/less/less.js)
at org.mozilla.javascript.optimizer.OptRuntime.callN(OptRuntime.java:52)
at org.mozilla.javascript.gen.file__D__Projects_lesscss_sources_compiler_target_classes_less_less_js_1._c_anonymous_2(file:/D:/Projects/lesscss/sources/compiler/target/classes/less/less.js:13)
at org.mozilla.javascript.gen.file__D__Projects_lesscss_sources_compiler_target_classes_less_less_js_1.call(file:/D:/Projects/lesscss/sources/compiler/target/classes/less/less.js)
at org.mozilla.javascript.optimizer.OptRuntime.call0(OptRuntime.java:23)
at org.mozilla.javascript.gen.file__D__Projects_lesscss_sources_compiler_target_classes_less_less_js_1._c_anonymous_1(file:/D:/Projects/lesscss/sources/compiler/target/classes/less/less.js:13)
at org.mozilla.javascript.gen.file__D__Projects_lesscss_sources_compiler_target_classes_less_less_js_1.call(file:/D:/Projects/lesscss/sources/compiler/target/classes/less/less.js)
at org.mozilla.javascript.optimizer.OptRuntime.call1(OptRuntime.java:32)
at org.mozilla.javascript.gen.file__D__Projects_lesscss_sources_compiler_target_classes_less_less_js_1._c_script_0(file:/D:/Projects/lesscss/sources/compiler/target/classes/less/less.js:13)
at org.mozilla.javascript.gen.file__D__Projects_lesscss_sources_compiler_target_classes_less_less_js_1.call(file:/D:/Projects/lesscss/sources/compiler/target/classes/less/less.js)
at org.mozilla.javascript.ContextFactory.doTopCall(ContextFactory.java:394)
at org.mozilla.javascript.ScriptRuntime.doTopCall(ScriptRuntime.java:3090)
at org.mozilla.javascript.gen.file__D__Projects_lesscss_sources_compiler_target_classes_less_less_js_1.call(file:/D:/Projects/lesscss/sources/compiler/target/classes/less/less.js)
at biz.gabrys.lesscss.compiler.LessCompilerImpl.compile(LessCompilerImpl.java:125)
... 25 more
```

There is also an unsolved issue associated with [Nashorn](https://github.com/less/less.js/issues/2063).